# Packrat: Dependencies unavailable

Tags: r, dependencies, packrat

I think I might be unsure of the workflow `packrat` expects.

I'm trying to make a docker image using `packrat` for dependencies management.  As a simple example, I've:

- Created a completely new project
- Ran

  - `packrat::on()`
  - `install.packages("RSQLite")`
  - `packrat::snapshot()`
- To the emulate the docker environment, I deleted all the `packrat/lib*` folder and `src`, as I would add these to the `.dockerignore`, as all the package information needed is in the `packrat.lock` file
- Then running `packrat::restore()` I hit the error:

(formatting messed up without a line here)

```
> packrat::restore()
Installing BH (1.62.0-1) ... 
    OK (built source)
Installing DBI (0.7) ... 
    OK (built source)
Installing RSQLite (2.0) ... 
Error: Command failed (1)

Failed to run system command:

    '/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --vanilla CMD INSTALL '/tmp/RtmppGgJVt/RSQLite' --library='/home/akhil/example/packrat/packrat/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.3.3' --install-tests --no-docs --no-multiarch --no-demo 

The command failed with output:
ERROR: dependencies 'bit64', 'blob' are not available for package 'RSQLite'
* removing '/home/akhil/example/packrat/packrat/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/3.3.3/RSQLite'
```

Slightly confused at what I should do at this point - `bit64` and `blob` are in the `lock` file, but I don't know how to tell packrat to install the dependencies first.

I get the same result using `packrat::bundle()` and `packrat::unbundle(..., restore = TRUE)` (which, from what I can see, does the same as I was doing, just keeping the `packrat/src/` folder).

Thanks

Comment: Relevant discussion relating to the issue on GitHub: https://github.com/rstudio/packrat/issues/391

Comment: That was me too :) the issue was fixed, it was a bug

Comment: I'm still struggling with something that I thought was the same, but the devtools installation of 0.4.8-49

Comment: Just checked the history, the fix has been confirmed as merged into master, so likely not the same problem unless it have cropped up again. If you think it ~is the same, you can `remotes::install_github(user/repo@commit_hash)` to see if it's a broken regression